# Updating emp information mysql query is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Trying to update employee information by using employee id (emp_id).

I have written the update query below. I have checked the table name and 
   database details all are correct but for some reason update query is not 
   running.

Is there any method to solve this issue?

```
<?php

session_start();
$id=$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];
//echo $id;
require_once('auth.php');
include('connection.php');
?>

<?php
$query2="SELECT * FROM add_employee where emp_id='$id'";
$result1=mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
{ 
   fullname=$row['fullname'];
   $email=$row['email'];
   $contact=$row['contact'];
   $address=$row['address'];
   $designation=$row['designation'];
   //$client_name=$row['client_name'];
   $joining_date=$row['joining_date'];
   $password=$row['password'];
   //$aadhartoupload=$row['aadhar'];
   $filetoupload=$row['photo'];
   //$resumetoupload=$row['resume'];
}
//die();
?>
```

Get Employee information

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){            
   $fullname=$_POST['fullname'];
   $email=$_POST['email'];
   $contact=$_POST['contact'];
   $address=$_POST['address'];
   $designation=$_POST['designation'];
   //$client_name=$_POST['client_name'];
   $joining_date=$_POST['joining_date'];
   $password=$_POST['password'];
```

Employee information update query

```
$sqlq= "UPDATE add_employee SET 
           fullname='$fullname',
           email='$email',
           contact='$contact',
           address='$address',
           designation='$designation',
           joining_date='$joining_date',
           password='$password' 
       WHERE 
           emp_id=$id";

$sqlqry= mysqli_query( $sqlq, $conn );

if ($sqlqry) { 
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Successful - Record Updated!'); window.location.href = 'user_profile.php';</script>"; 
 } else { 
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Unsuccessful - ERROR!'); window.location.href = 'user_dashboard.php';</script>"; 
 }
}
?>
<!-- end of update profile code!-->
```

```
<form action="user_profile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>EMP ID</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control border-input" id="emp_id" name="emp_id" placeholder="Employee Id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" disabled>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Fullname</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control border-input" id="fullname" name="fullname" placeholder="fullname" value="<?php echo $fullname; ?>">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-5">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Email address</label>
                                                <input type="email" class="form-control border-input" name="email" placeholder="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Contact number</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control border-input" name="contact"placeholder="Contact" value="<?php echo $contact; ?>">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Designation</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control border-input" name="designation" placeholder="Your Designation" value="<?php echo $designation; ?>" disabled>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-5">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Client Name</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control border-input" name="client_name" placeholder="Client Name" value="<?php echo $client_name; ?>" disabled>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Address</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control border-input" name="address" placeholder="Address" value="<?php echo $address; ?>">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Joining Date</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control border-input" name="joining_date" placeholder="Joining Date" value="<?php echo $joining_date; ?>" disabled>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Change password</label>
                                                <input type="password" class="form-control border-input" name="password" placeholder="Country" value="<?php echo $password; ?>">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <!--<div class="col-md-4">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Upload Aadhar</label>
                                                <input type="file" name="aadhar" id="aadhar" value="<?php //echo $aadhartoupload; ?>" >
                                            </div>
                                        </div>!-->
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Upload photo</label>
                                                <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" value="<?php echo $filetoupload; ?>" >
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!--<div class="col-md-4">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Upload Resume</label>
                                                <input type="file" name="resume" id="resume" value="<?php //echo $resumetoupload; ?>" >
                                            </div>
                                        </div>!-->
                                    </div>



                                    <div class="text-center">
                                        <!--class="btn btn-info btn-fill btn-wd"!-->
                                        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-fill btn-wd">Update Profile</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </form>
```

Comment: Hi Rohit. Welcome to StackOverflow!. Can you please include any error messages?

Comment: 1) your code is wide open to sql injection attacks and if any of the input fields contain a single quote, then it will throw your query off 2) I do not see any forms that could be sumitted to update the data 3) where does $id come from?

Comment: Hi Ahmad, Thank you for the reply, I did not get any error message after submitting the form I only get alert('Unsuccessful - ERROR!')

Comment: Hi Shadow, Thank you for instant reply, I have added the form  in my question, Please check.

Comment: Well, in the else branch you could print out the actual error message and the you would know what's going on.

Comment: print your query, run it in sql and check the result.

Comment: Hi Shadow, after submitting the form query printing the updated data but after refresh the page updated data will go off https://prnt.sc/lrdq6x

Comment: Getting below error
Warning: mysqli_query(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you need to check your sql statement near `WHERE emp_id=$id`. Try rather using `WHERE emp_id='$id'`.Those quotes might be the difference.

Comment: Encouraging to use string interpolation without any attempt to prevent sql injection is a very bad advice!

Comment: @Shadow, I am also new to SO so I thought there should be people who are not yet interested in prepared statements but rather finding out what's preventing their code from running.I get you though

Comment: Not interested or just unaware?

Comment: okay noted.Will use that approach in future

Comment: @Twista Thank you for your help it worked for me :)

Comment: You are welcome, but as @Shadow already mentioned, please do consider prepared statements otherwise your sql is unsafe.